# How are the values of the Grubbs table calculated for use in the Grubbs filter?

Tags: filter, data-preprocessing

I am looking at [Grubbs test for outliers](http://webspace.ship.edu/pgmarr/Geo441/Readings/Grubbs%201969%20-%20Detecting%20outlying%20observations%20in%20samples.pdf). The approach seems simple enough but for completeness I have two questions.

The Grubbs test is defined as
$$G_{\rm{test}} = \frac{\left| x_{i} - \bar{x} \right|}{s}$$
where $x_i$ is the value we want to test, $\bar{x}$ is the mean of the sample to which $x_i$ belongs, and $s$ is the standard deviation of the sample.

There is a table of values for the Grubbs test which goes with $N$ the number of data points in the sample and the confidence level at which you want to test at. For example:
\begin{array}{c|lcr}& \textbf{N} & 99\% & 95\% 
\\\hline & 3 & 1.155 & 1.153 
\\       & 4 & 1.492 & 1.463   
\\       & 5 & 1.749 & 1.672
\\       & 6 & 1.973 & 1.822
\\       & ... & ... & ...
\end{array}

I can't seem to find the calculation to determine these values shown in the table.

1. How does one calculate the Grubbs test value for a given confidence level and number of points?
2. Is there a limit of the number of points where the Grubbs test is no longer valid - -I ask as the Grubbs value table only goes to around $N=20$, this may just be convenience but I wanted to check that the Grubbs filter/test wasn't limited to small sample sizes.

---

One possible solution to my first question to calculate the test values is
$$\Phi^{-1} \left( 1 - \frac{\alpha}{2} \right)$$ where the confidence interval is defined as $C=100(1 - \alpha)\%$

Comment: The theory is given in section (5) of Grubbs' original paper, available online at https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177729885.

Comment: @whuber Yes I read that section but it wasn't clear to me. I found an article from NIST: https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda3672.htm which explains it in a way which is more intuitive to me. But I can't replicate the results, let me add a little more to my question.

Comment: The calculation is not an easy one: it requires iterating an integration $n-2$ times and must be done numerically.  I'm not surprised you haven't replicated it.  Your link is to a description of the Student $t$ distribution, which is not directly relevant here.

Comment: Okay then my approach was totally wrong, in that link I interpreted $t(\nu, x)$ as the CDF of a student's t-distribution, where the degrees of freedom, $\nu$, are the number of points, and then evaluate for $x = 1-\alpha$ or $x = 1-\alpha/2$. This also explains why these tables seem to stop at $n = 100$. I was thinking what if your data set has $n= 1000$ data points?! But the degrees of freedom refer to the individual data points-- as you described in my previous question.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the Critical_value from python or Mathematica.  from python3 it would look like:

```
from scipy import stats
def Gcritical(n, CL):
    #computes the GcriticalValue from the confidence level
    Tcritical = stats.t.isf((1 - CL/100.)/n, n-2)
    return (n - 1)/sqrt(n)*sqrt(Tcritical**2/(n - 2 + Tcritical**2))
```

where n is the number of samples and CL is the confidence level in a percent, like 99.5.  in mathematica it is similar.